# Naming the image while saving it in python

Tags: python, count, naming

I crop a serial of images and save it

with the code

```
# Setting the points for cropped image
w, h = im.size

# Pixel size for each image
pixel = 100


# Number of images for each layer
Column = 20


#layer
Roll = 20

# Step of each image
step = int((w/int(Column)))
Roll_step = int((h/int(Roll)))
for b in range(1, int(Roll)+1):
    count = 1
    for a in range(int(Column)):
        left = a * int(step)
        top = (b - 1) * int(Roll_step)
        right = int(pixel) + a * int(step)
        bottom = int(pixel) + (b - 1) * int(Roll_step)
        im1 = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
        im1.save(f"layer {b:02}_{count:03}.jpg")
        count += 1
```

The file name will be saved as [layer 01_001, layer 01_002,....layer 01_999]

I want to add a count in the front so that the name will be saved as[ 001_layer 01_001, 002_layer 01_002,....999_layer 01_999]

I used

```
im1.save(f"{count:03}+'_'+layer {b:02}_{count:03}.jpg")
```

But it didn't work

How to save the name

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Why not just `f"{count:03}_layer {b:02}_{count:03}.jpg"` ?

Comment: @alaniwi It works! Thank you!!